# In what way is classList read only?

Tags: javascript

According to W3Schools:

> The classList property is read-only

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

However this works fine:

```
document.querySelector('body').classList = 'body-class';
```

Live Example:

```js
document.querySelector('body').classList = 'body-class';
```

```css
.body-class {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
Testing 1 2 3
```

Is this usage a hack?

Comment: `classList` is a **DOMTokenList** with functions. You're just overriding them with a string, which can't be considered as _"works fine"_

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi - Are you sure about that?

Comment: Ooh, actually it seems to apply the _value_ of that list with string, I stand corrected. So basically doing the same as `document.body.classList.add('body-class')`

Comment: Do not confuse W3Schools (advertising riddled low quality tutorial mill with good SEO) with the W3C (standards organisation).

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi: it seems to *replace* the content instead of adding it. But I've not found a spec for this at a quick search.

Comment: [WG docs state](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element) `readonly attribute DOMTokenList classList;`

Comment: @Liam — That's WHAT WG not W3C

Comment: Personally I find [MDN has really good documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), with links to the appropriate standards.

Comment: You should instead do `document.querySelector('body').classList.add('body-class');` if you want to use `classList` the intended way. I see you found that out yourself :)

Comment: `classList` is defined with both setter and getter and is not a regular object property. Assigning to it merely invokes the setter.

Comment: @skolind - That doesn't do the same thing, if `body` already has any classes. The equivalent would be to assign to `className`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh yes, if the goal is to override all classes, then yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [DOM specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element), the attribute is indeed `readonly`:

```
 [SameObject, PutForwards=value] readonly attribute DOMTokenList classList;
```

From the spec:

> The attribute is read only if the `readonly` keyword is used before the attribute keyword. An object that implements the interface on which a read only attribute is defined will not allow assignment to that attribute. It is language binding specific whether assignment is simply disallowed by the language, ignored or an exception is thrown.

But you can also see a `PutForwards=value` there:

> If the [PutForwards] extended attribute appears on a read only regular attribute declaration whose type is an interface type, it indicates that assigning to the attribute will have specific behavior. Namely, the assignment is “forwarded” to the attribute (specified by the extended attribute argument) on the object that is currently referenced by the attribute being assigned to.

The value of `.classList` is a [`DOMTokenList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#domtokenlist). So if you assign to `classList`, you are really assigning to `.classList.value`.

```
interface DOMTokenList {
  ...
  [CEReactions] stringifier attribute DOMString value;
};
```

---

Some people say that it's a bug: It could very well be that it was unspecified behavior or that browsers thought that it would be a useful feature, despite what the official spec says. Sometimes specifications get updated to reflect reality and it could be that the `PutForwards=value` part was added at some point.

Comment: I think we can be sure it wasn't a *bug*. It may have been because some early implementation did this thinking it was a good idea (?!), but it wouldn't be *by accident*. They'd have to do it on purpose. :-| (Wow, `classList` was in Firefox 3.6 10 years ago!)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yeah, let me rephrase that.